# Macbook Pro Overheating - Bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I have a 2009 Macbook Pro that dual-boots Windows 7. It's been working great until one day, I took a 4 hour drive on a hot day with my laptop in the trunk… yeah… So here's what happens:

1. I start Windows 7 and it takes about 5 - 10 minutes for Windows Explorer to start up, and each time I restart it feels like it takes a little longer.
   Once it finally does and I can click around,
2. Although the computer is only launching a few (known) startup processes, and nothing graphically intensive at all, the GPU and both cores shoot up to 75C and stay there for a while.

If I close the laptop and let it rest for a while, and reopen it, it can decide to be anywhere between 45C and 65C, even while effectively idling.

On the Mac OS side of the drive, the temperature does not shoot up this high unless I am pushing the computer with movies or serious number crunching.

I am 85-90% sure there is no virus on the Windows side. All that said, I'm worried Windows will get to a point where it simply won't start. And I don't understand why the computer heats up for no apparent reason. I haven't messed with the BIOS or overclocked anything. So I have three questions:

Q1 - Any idea why the computer overheats for no reason when I start Windows?

Q2 - Any idea why Windows Explorer takes longer and longer to start up?

Q3 - If I transfer my partition to VMWare, do you think I will have the same problem, or will the magic of Apple protect me?